# Why one bootstrap swiper innerHTML not updating?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, swiper.js

```js
document.querySelector('#info_banner_merch').innerHTML = lang.info_banner_merch;
document.querySelector('#info_banner_website').innerHTML = lang.info_banner_website;
document.querySelector('#info_banner_team').innerHTML = lang.info_banner_team;
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <span id="info_banner_merch" class="d-inline-block font-sm color-brand-2"></span>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <span id="info_banner_website" class="d-inline-block font-sm color-brand-2"></span>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <span id="info_banner_team" class="d-inline-block font-sm color-brand-2"></span>
</div>
```

The Objects are all updating the innerHTML-values but the last element ('info_banner_team') doesn't show the updated text. If i press the swiper in the opposite direction (previous-button) it displays it right. Anyone have any idea?

**EDIT:
I have a swiper with 3 elements. The swiper has also "go next" and "go previous" buttons to switch the shown element. If i go through "go next" the last of the 3 elements doesn't display any Text. If i go through "go previous" the text is shown correctly.**

Update each swiper-element with html text. 2 are working, the last one isn't.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough of the relevant code in the question to recreate the problem in order to debug it. Can you please edit to add all relevant code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.